# Python Pandas: Joining Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have table A and Table B. I want to join them to get Table C. I tried the following code. But it is not giving me the result that I want.

```
C = pd.merge(A, B, how = 'inner', left_on = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'], right_on = ['IDA', 'IDB', 'IDC'])
```

Table A

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | Color | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | White | Y |
| B | 1 | 2 | Black | Y |
| A | 1 | 3 | Green | N |
| E | 2 | 3 | Blue | Y |
| D | 4 | 5 | Blue | N |
| C | 6 | 7 | Red | N |
| F | 9 | 7 | Black | Y |

Table B

| IDA | IDB | IDC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| F | 9 | 7 |
| A | 1 | 3 |
| D | 4 | 5 |

Table C

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | Color | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | White | Y |
| A | 1 | 3 | Green | N |
| D | 4 | 5 | Blue | N |
| F | 9 | 7 | Black | Y |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# do a left merge and rop the null rows
out=(pd.merge(df, df2, 
          how = 'left', 
          left_on = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'], 
          right_on = ['IDA', 'IDB', 'IDC'])
 .dropna()
 .drop(columns=['IDA', 'IDB','IDC']))
```

```
ID1     ID2     ID3     Color   Flag
0   A   1   1   White   Y
2   A   1   3   Green   N
4   D   4   5   Blue    N
6   F   9   7   Black   Y
```

alternately, if these are the only columns in your DF, you can convert these to string to make them of same type. that too is only for join and not affecting the DFs

```
(pd.merge(df.astype(str), df2.astype(str), 
          how = 'left', 
          left_on = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'], 
          right_on = ['IDA', 'IDB', 'IDC'])
 .dropna()
 .drop(columns=['IDA', 'IDB','IDC']))
```

```
    ID1     ID2     ID3     Color   Flag
0   A   1   1   White   Y
2   A   1   3   Green   N
4   D   4   5   Blue    N
6   F   9   7   Black   Y
```

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Comment: No. If Col ID1 and IDA have different data types, will that affect anything?

Comment: @NEWBIE, Yes the types needs to be same. what is the datatype for each of them?

Comment: @NEWBIE, refer to the alternate solution